# How to check if a collection exists in Mongodb native nodejs driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I need to check if a collection exists on a certain database and create it if it doesn't. I know that

```
db.createCollection(collName, {strict:true}, function(error, collection))
```

checks for existance of collection `collName` before creating it and sets `error` object. but I need an independent function to check that.

Comment: more information required: which connector library are you using, and have you checked its manual/api documents?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm using [mongo-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) driver library, and I couldn't find such functionality in it's API documents.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**In MongoDB 3.0 and later, you have to run a command to list all collections in a database:**

```
use test;
db.runCommand( { listCollections: 1 } );
```

Although querying `system.namespaces` will still work when you use the default storage engine (MMAPv1), it is not guaranteed to work for other engines, such as WiredTiger.

**Before MongoDB 3.0 you need to do the following:**

You can query the `system.namespaces` collection:

```
use test;
db.system.namespace.find( { name: 'test.' + collName } );
```

Like in:

```
db.system.namespaces.find( { name: 'test.testCollection' } );
```

Which returns:

```
{ "name" : "test.testCollection", "options" : { "flags" : 1 } }
```

Or of course, nothing.

*See also: https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/enumerate-collections.rst*

Comment: in [mongo-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native): `db.collection('system.namespaces').find().toArray(function(err, items) {})`

Comment: Late to the party, but I think my answer below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/40141321/446717) has a more direct and clean approach to get that info

Comment: None of this in the answer is available in the native node.js lib. Only working thing is what Nasser provided.

Comment: As of today, this answer no longer holds valid, 

`
db.listCollections({name: collName})
    .next(function(err, collinfo) {
        if (collinfo) {
            // The collection exists
        }
    });
`

is a valid answer from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28921019/3861525)

Comment: how do you get this db object in nodejs?

Answer (score 68):

The [`collectionNames`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#collectionnames) method of the native driver's `Db` object accepts an optional collection name filter as a first parameter to let you check the existence of a collection:

```
db.collectionNames(collName, function(err, names) {
    console.log('Exists: ', names.length > 0);
});
```

In the 2.x version of the MongoDB native driver, `collectionNames` has been replaced by [`listCollections`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html#listCollections) which accepts a filter and returns a cursor so you would do this as:

```
db.listCollections({name: collName})
    .next(function(err, collinfo) {
        if (collinfo) {
            // The collection exists
        }
    });
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is the only answer that actually deals with node.js (like OP asked for).

Comment: also one liner `db.listCollections({ name: colName }).hasNext()`

Answer (score 25):

<s>Using [mongo-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) driver and [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) 7.6+, I use the following:</s>

```
const collections = await db.collections();
if (!collections.map(c => c.s.name).includes(collName)) {
    await db.createCollection(collName);
}
```

### EDIT

As @MattCochrane mentions, `collection.s.name` is no longer available; as @JohnnyHK and @weekens point out, the correct way is to use the [`listCollections()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Db.html#listCollections) method:

```
const client = new MongoClient(connectionString, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
await client.connect();
const collections = await client.db().listCollections().toArray();
const collectionNames = collections.map(c => c.name);
```

`listCollection()` takes an optional filter.

Comment: Just tested this Node v8.11.4 - mongodb - 3.1.10: and it works great!

Comment: You could make this a little shorter with `some()` instead of `map` and `includes` 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: **This no longer works in mongodb 3.6.0**, the `name` property is not available on `collection.s` .  A lesson for me.. I should have known better than to use what is clearly not intended to be a public interface.

Answer (score 6):

Since MongoDB 3.0 you can simply run:

```
db.getCollectionNames()
```

which returns an array with the names of all the collections on current database:

```
[ "employees", "products", "mylogs"]
```

check [Mongo DB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/#db-getcollectionnames), or you could also use db.getCollectionInfos() if you need more info about each collection

Comment: The method `getCollectionNames()` is not available in node.js native lib.

Comment: Hey, but I'm using it from mongodb lib, which is the one that manages the mongo database @DanFromGermany

Comment: There is [`Db.collectionNames()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/collections.html#list-existing-collections) in the older API available but not `getCollectionNames()` at all.

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you using, this getCollectionNames() exists in MongoDB 3.0

Comment: Dude, the latest node driver for mongo is [`2.2` (link)](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/). 3.0 does not even exist.

Answer (score 5):

There is now a [listCollections](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html#listCollections) method in Node.js native driver. It returns information on all collections in current database. You can use it to check if a given collection is there:

```
collectionExists = function(name, cb) {
  mongoDb.listCollections().toArray(function(err, collections) {
    if (err) return cb(err);

    cb(null, collections.some(function(coll) {
      return coll.name == name;
    }));
  });
}
```

Comment: @NikolaLukic in `cb` function, first argument is an error (`null` if no error), second argument is boolean, that is `true` if collection exists and `false` if not. `collectionExists` function can also be implemented with promises instead of callbacks.

Comment: I already have same info with listCollections().toArray . I need to write simple function like : isExist (name ) , and use it like if ( isExist('mycollection') == true) { doSomething(); } Maybe i will need async methods...

Comment: @NikolaLukic, yes, you will probably end up with `if (await isExist('mycollection'))` or `if (yield isExist('mycollection'))`. There is no other way to make asynchronous method look like synchronous one. I guess, `== true` is redundant.

Answer (score 5):

If you use mongodb 3.1.10.
This is how to check if collections exist.

```
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, client) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var dbo = client.db("dbname");
  dbo.listCollections().toArray(function(err, items){
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(items); 
    if (items.length == 0)
        console.log("No collections in database")  
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

actually, this works for me

```
  await db.createCollection(name, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        //console.log(err);
        if (err.codeName =="NamespaceExists") {
            console.log("Already Exists Collection  : " + name + "");
            return;
        }
    }
    console.log("Collection created! : "+name+"");

});
```

Answer (score 3):

An async TypeScript function:

```
/**
 * Predicate function that checks if a collection exists in a given MongoDB database
 *
 * @param {Db} db Mongo database instance
 * @param {string} collectionName Name of collection
 *
 * @returns {boolean} true if collection exists, false otherwise
 */
export const doesCollectionExist = async (db: Db, collectionName: string): Promise<boolean> => {
  const cursor = db.listCollections({ name: collectionName })
  const result = await cursor.hasNext()
  await cursor.close()

  return result
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An updated answer which works with 3.6.* releases.

```js
/**
 * Checks if a collection exists in a mongo database.
 * 
 * @param db a mongo db object.  eg.
 *    client = await MongoClient.connect(uri);
 *    db = client.db();
 * @param collectionName the name of the collection to search for
 * @returns {Promise<boolean>}
 */
async function doesCollectionExistInDb(db, collectionName) {
  const collections = await db.collections();
  return collections.some(
      (collection) => collection.collectionName === collectionName
  );
}

...

if (await doesCollectionExistInDb(db, 'products')) {
   // Do something, such as create a new collection
}
```

The `collection.collectionName` is part of the documented collection api as can be found here: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#collectionName

Comment: This worked for me in 2021, great clean solution!

Answer (score 2):

For nodejs with mongodb library (v 3.6.3) that's the only way I got it working:

```
const collectionName = 'products'
const exists = (await (await db.listCollections().toArray()).findIndex((item) => item.name === collectionName) !== -1)
console.log(exists)
```

Hope that helps others

Answer (score 1):

The question refers to the native driver, but I got here searching how to do this in `pymongo`. Usually `pymongo`'s api is identical to the JS api, but in this case `collection_names` doesn't have an argument for the collection's name (as in `JohnnyHK`'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28921019/165753)), but rather the first argument is a boolean (whether to include system collections). Since a string evaluates to `True`, this can be confusing. So I hope this helps future readers:

```
import pymongo

cl = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = cl['my-db']
if 'my-col' in db.collection_names(False):
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* set database */
let db          = client.db( 'crud' )

/* set collection */
let collection  = db.collection( 'categories' )

/* set query */
collection.find( {} ).toArray( ( err, result ) => {

if ( result.length > 0 )
{
    console.log("Exist");
}
else
{
    console.log("Not Exist");

    // create collection
}
```

}